# Cannot find eclipse-cdt.xml to set C/C++ Paths and Symbols in Eclipse CDT for a Chromium project

Tags: android, xml, node.js, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to import the chromium project in Eclipse,by following the steps in this [link](https://www.chromium.org/developers/android-eclipse-dev).

In the following step we need to create "eclipse-cdt.xml file" as per

```
C/C++ Paths and Symbols. This help Eclipse build the symbol table for Chrome.
    From a shell, run GYP_GENERATORS=eclipse build/gyp_chromium
    This generates <project root>/out/Release/eclipse-cdt-settings.xml which is used below.
    Select C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols from the tree on the left
    Click Restore Defaults to clear any old settings
    Click Import Settings... The import dialog should appear.
    Click Browse... A file browser should appear.
    Select <project root>/out/Release/eclipse-cdt-settings.xml.
    Click the Finish button. The entire preferences dialog should go away.
    Right click on the project and select Index > Rebuild
```

But the command  run GYP_GENERATORS=eclipse build/gyp_chromium is giving error.

I did some more research, and found that we need to run this **Nodejs** project([link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)) which has (node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/eclipse.py) a eclipse.py file, which generates the eclipse-cdt.xml file.

But this project also requires the binding.gyp file which is not there in that project directory.

Can anybody please help me how to write this file????
Or, Is there any other way to generate the eclipse-cdt.xml file ???

I am totally new to this environment, so please forgive me if I have missed something Important

Thanks!